# How to join 2 sql tables where one table contains multiple values in a single column

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, this is what my SELECT code looks like:

```
SELECT student.stu_code, user.f_name, user.l_name 
FROM user
INNER JOIN student
ON student.stu_code = user.user_id 
INNER JOIN course 
ON course.stu_code ?????;
```

Basically, to elaborate the student table inherits from user table, therefore I had user_id = stu_code. What I'm confused about is how to join course table with student table.

Let's say that the course table has a course code (PK), a few other attributes and a stu_code column, however, the student code column has multiple values inside a single column to represent that multiple students are taking the course and stored as VARCHAR.

Example: Student table has stu_code string value of '123' and course table has a stu_code with string value of '123, 246, 369'.
How would I go about joining these two tables together and separating the stu_code in the course table so that it represents 3 separate stu_code values -> i.e. '123', '246', '369'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not too long for a comment: normalise your schema!

Answer (score 1):

> however, the student code column has multiple values inside a single column to represent that multiple students are taking the course and stored as VARCHAR.

Your data model is broken.  Put your effort into fixing the data model.  You want a junction/association table `courseStudents` or perhaps `enrolled`, with columns like:

- `stu_code` (foreign key to students)
- `course_code` (foreign key to students)
- `enrollment_date`
- and so on

What is wrong with your data model?  Here are a few things:

- You are storing numbers as a string.
- You are putting multiple values into a string column.
- You cannot define foreign key relationships.
- SQL has poor string handling capabilities.
- SQL has a great way to store lists of things.  It is not called "string". It is called "table".

Comment: Thanks for your input, the numbers represent a code and I'm not going to be performing any calculations on it, so it's fine as a string.
As for the putting multiple values into a single column, I heard that it was possible, is it not?
I have foreign key relationships, I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to here.

If the approach I have taken is wrong, how would you go about listing the stu_code for students who take a certain course? Put the course_code into the student table instead -> to represent which students enrolled in what course?

Comment: Either way, whether I have enrollment for courses, if a course has multiple students, and each student enrolls in many courses, doesn't that mean I would have to have multiple values in a single column regardless?
If I put it into a new table called enrolled, either there will be multiple stu_code values for each course_code or multiple course_code values for each stu_code unless I'm misunderstanding something and being dumb.

Comment: @Bombolz . . . Possible, yes.  Desirable?  Absolutely not.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is ~broken~ hindering you from elegant solutions.

You cannot join your two tables efficiently.  While they might both contain strings they do not contain data with the same rules. Thus, you must transform the data in order to join them so you could do this in a few ways but one way is using regular expression function.

You can use it to evaluate a test on whether the `stu_code` matches the list of codes.  Further, you can do this dynamically ... constructing the test string itself based upon values from the left and right

#### join based on REGEXP

```
SELECT student.stu_code, user.f_name, user.l_name 
FROM user
INNER JOIN student
ON student.stu_code = user.user_id 
INNER JOIN course 
ON student.stu_code REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',course.stu_code,'[[:>:]]')
```

#### Assuming tables and data:

```
Student
- - - - 
stu_code
123     


Course
- - - - 
stu_code     
'123, 246, 369'
```

#### Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/672b57f/4

#### about the regular expression

in mysql the regex syntax can be a little bit different.  `[[:<:]]` is the character class in spencer notation for word boundary.
if you have a new enough version of mysql/mariadb you can use more typical ICU notation of `\b`.

more about that here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

#### about efficiency

in large datasets the performance will be awful. you will have to scan all records and you will have to perform the function on all of them.  In a large set you might get some gains by joining on `like` first (which is faster than regexp).  This will be much faster at filtering-out and then the regexp can deal with filtering-in.

Perhaps your model was based upon an assumption of having a courses table with very few rows?
It ironic because you have made your course table unnecessarily large. You would actually be better off with an intermediary table that represents the many-to-many nature (the fact that students can take many courses and courses can have many students) with 1 row per unique relationship. While this table would be an order of magnitude "longer" it would be leaner and it could be indexed and query performance would be faster.
The courses table does not need to have any awareness of the student list and thus you can alter courses by removing courses.stu_code once you change the model (aside: It might be useful if courses cached a hint of the expected student count for that course)

##### possible link table

would be a new table like this (note how it only ever needs these 2 columns)

```
stu_course_lnk
- - - - - - - - 
stu_code course_id
123       ABC
124       ABC
...
123       XYZ
...
124       LMN
```

then you add joins of

```
...
student.stu_code = stu_course_lnk.stu_code
and 
stu_course_lnk.course_id = course.id
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to give this a go. I know the data model isn't the best, but I'm following a specification.